# Numpy array of pairs: remove multiples based on score

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of pairs. Second value in pair is a score.
Among elements where first value in pair is equal I only want to keep the one with the highest score/highest second value. I can sort the list by either index but found no tutorial in how to extract parts of this list to pick each winner from each part.

```
pairs = np.array([[2., 0.5], [2., 0.9],[3., 0.9], [2., 0.3], [8., 0.77], [8., 0.93],[2., 0.8]])
```

should be:

```
np.array([[2., 0.9],[3., 0.9], [8., 0.93]])
```

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
"I'm stuck" is not a problem specification.

Comment: Less useful than the other answers but probably took the same time to write.

Comment: @Oortone he is right, though :D but still it was an interesting question

Comment: New to Python I have spent weeks learning how to handle the rather confusing mix of arrays and list of various and similar kind found in standard Python, Pandas and Numpy and solved at least 30 problems by myself. The only problem with my question was that I wrote "I'm s..." (better not write it again). Obviously you and others found it interesting. Prune's comment would be ok if he'd linked to the tutorial where he says I could easily found the answer. When that's not provided, maybe the question was not trivial and easily found in a tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

I have it down to a loop.

```
import numpy as np

pairs = np.array([[2., 0.5], [2., 0.9],[3., 0.9], [2., 0.3], [8., 0.77], [8., 0.93],[2., 0.8]])

winners = []
for left in np.unique(pairs[:,0]):
    winners.append( np.max(pairs[pairs[:,0] == left], 0) )
print( np.array(winners) )
```

That can be reduced to a one-line list comprehension.  Not sure it would be clearer.

```
winners = [np.max(pairs[pairs[:,0] == left], 0) for left in np.unique(pairs[:,0])]
```

Output:

```
C:\tmp>python x.py
[[2.   0.9 ]
 [3.   0.9 ]
 [8.   0.93]]

C:\tmp>
```

You could do it with grouping in pandas, but that's a big package to draw in for one function.

Answer (score 1):

I converted array to dataframe and implemented simple groupby. You can convert the final result to array if you want.

```
pairs = np.array([[2., 0.5], [2., 0.9],[3., 0.9], [2., 0.3], [8., 0.77], [8., 0.93], 
[2., 0.8]])


df = pd.DataFrame(pairs, columns = ['Index', 'Score'])

df.groupby(['Index'])['Score'].max()
```

Output:

```
Index
2.0    0.90
3.0    0.90
8.0    0.93
Name: Score, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

1. Sort the array, first by first value, then by score in descending order
2. Find the indices of the unique elements in the first column
3. Take the elements of the sorted pairs at these indices

In code:

```
import numpy as np
pairs = np.array([[2., 0.5], [2., 0.9], [3., 0.9], [2., 0.3], [8., 0.77], [8., 0.93], [2., 0.8]])
sorted_pairs = pairs[np.lexsort((-pairs[:,1], pairs[:,0]))] # minus sign for descending order
indices = np.unique(sorted_pairs[:,0], return_index=True)[1]
result = sorted_pairs[indices]
```

Then, in your example:

```
>>> result
array([[2.  , 0.9 ],
       [3.  , 0.9 ],
       [8.  , 0.93]])
```

No for loop, no pandas involved.